# SVG positioning dasharray at top

Tags: arrays, svg, shapes, svg-animate

I would like to get a 'T shape' at the top of the SVG Circle, but cant seem to get it to display correctly. I have the used **stroke-dasharray** to split the circle up, however I can only get them on the right-hand side, ideally would like to get them on the top, thus creating the 'T shape'.

Could someone please guide me in the right direction?

```
<body style="background:#f3f3f3;margin: 0 auto;  padding: 0;width:100%; height:500px;">
    <svg width="100%" max-height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 380 320" enable-background="new 0 0 404.7 354" id="logo"> 
        <!-- Backing Circle -->
        <circle stroke-opacity="0.4" r="42%" cy="50%" cx="50%" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" fill="#000" fill-opacity="0" style="fill-opacity: 0.7;"></circle>
        <!-- Inner circle - opacity 0.4 -->
        <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M 127, 160 m -77.5, 0 a 79,79 0 1,0 281,0 a 79,79 0 1,0 -281,0" style="opacity:0.4"></path>
        <!-- 'T' Line -->
        <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" d="M190,21.5L190,220" style="stroke-dashoffset: 0px;"></path>

        <!-- Inner circle - opacity 1 -->
        <circle stroke-opacity="1" r="40%" id="circleAni" cy="50%" cx="50%" stroke-width="4" stroke="#ffffff" fill="none" data-svg-origin="200 200" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); opacity: 1; stroke-dashoffset: 0px; stroke-dasharray: 110.69px, 60.38px, 664.16px, 60.38px, 110.69px; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;"></circle>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: removed erroneous explanation and replaced it with corrected information**

The "start" of a circle is at the 3 o'clock position. So to position the "T" segments 3/4 of the way around the circle at the top, you need to start with a long first dash segment.

```html
    <svg width="100%" max-height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 380 320" enable-background="new 0 0 404.7 354" id="logo"> 
        <!-- Backing Circle -->
        <circle stroke-opacity="0.4" r="42%" cy="50%" cx="50%" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" fill="#000" fill-opacity="0" style="fill-opacity: 0.7;"></circle>
        <!-- Inner circle - opacity 0.4 -->
        <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M 127, 160 m -77.5, 0 a 79,79 0 1,0 281,0 a 79,79 0 1,0 -281,0" style="opacity:0.4"></path>
        <!-- 'T' Line -->
        <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" d="M190,21.5L190,220" style="stroke-dashoffset: 0px;"></path>

        <!-- Inner circle - opacity 1 -->
        <circle stroke-opacity="1" r="40%" id="circleAni" cy="50%" cx="50%" stroke-width="4" stroke="#ffffff" fill="none" data-svg-origin="200 200" 
            
        style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
               opacity: 1;
               stroke-dashoffset: 0;
               stroke-dasharray: 547, 60.38, 110.69, 60.38, 664.16;
               transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;"></circle>
    </svg>
```

Another alternative is to use a transform to rotate the circle around to the correct position, but that is often more trouble than it is worth.

Or you could replace the `<circle>` with a `<path>`.  Then have the path start at a later position in the circle.  For example I have started at the left (9 o'clock) in the following example.

```html
    <svg width="100%" max-height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 380 320" enable-background="new 0 0 404.7 354" id="logo"> 
        <!-- Backing Circle -->
        <circle stroke-opacity="0.4" r="42%" cy="50%" cx="50%" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" fill="#000" fill-opacity="0" style="fill-opacity: 0.7;"></circle>
        <!-- Inner circle - opacity 0.4 -->
        <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M 127, 160 m -77.5, 0 a 79,79 0 1,0 281,0 a 79,79 0 1,0 -281,0" style="opacity:0.4"></path>
        <!-- 'T' Line -->
        <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" d="M190,21.5L190,220" style="stroke-dashoffset: 0px;"></path>

        <!-- Inner circle - opacity 1 -->
     <path d="M 50,160 A 140,140 0 0 1 330,160 A 140,140 0 0 1 50,160 Z"
           stroke-opacity="1"
           r="140"
           id="circleAni"
           cy="160"
           cx="190"
           stroke-width="4"
           stroke="#ffffff"
           fill="none"
           data-svg-origin="200 200"
           style="opacity: 1;
                  stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
                  stroke-dasharray: 104.19px, 60.38, 110.69, 60.38, 664.16;
                  transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: **Does too say** [The arc of a ‘circle’ element begins at the "3 o'clock" point on the radius and progresses towards the "9 o'clock" point.](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#CircleElement)

Comment: Awesome, cheers Paul. I was looking to use path rather than circle and stroke. And @RobertLongson for your additional info, much appreciated.

Comment: Whoops - red face. Should have checked that instead of going by memory.  Thanks Robert.